# yii2 / Migration Not Working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
 public function up() {
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
        $columns = [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
            'price' => $this->decimal(10, 2)->notNull()->defaultValue(0),
            'original_price' => $this->decimal(10, 2)->notNull()->defaultValue(0),
            'special_price' => $this->decimal(10, 2)->notNull()->defaultValue(0),
            'comment' => $this->string(10),
            'is_deleted' => $this->boolean()->defaultValue(0),
            'created_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
            'updated_at' => $this->ti`enter code here`mestamp()
        ];
        $this->createTable('tbl_ironing_order_item', $columns, $tableOptions);
    }
```

i am using yii2 framework, i deploy project on server migrations run working fine, recently create new modules that migrations not run on serve, not showing any error,
**How can i run migrations at deploy time?**

Comment: You have to run `php yii migrate`. Remember that the files need to follow the naming convention for mugrations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the migration files are on  **console/migrations** directory.
If they are not in that directory, you could specify the directories they are in.

Run

```
php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/path/to/your/migrations
```